# How to create a closed redstone circuit on a timer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-railcraft

I'm pretty new to Minecraft and redstone stuff so I'm trying to figure out how to make a closed circuit from a lever that will turn off moments after you switch it.

As you can see here:
[image: Off]

and here: [image: On]

I've figured out how to make the redstone travel and turn on the railway switch. My overall goal is to be able to go down the pink path on a cart, be slowed down to a stop by the powered rail hit an initial switch that will turn the rail from path A (marked by the gray terracotta) to path B (marked by the black and red terracotta.), where I can then move to another powered rail to send me on my way.

So I guess what I am asking is: How do I make it so that the switch will turn the railway and then switch it back after I have moved past it? And since the powered rails are there to stop the cart on one rail and then boost after the switch, will I have to do the same for the those on each side of the rail switch as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minecraft has two signal types, a pulse and a continuous charge (these might not be the official names, i forget) . A pulse occurs when you press a button. Its an 'on' followed by a delay of a certain amount of time (based on button type) and then it turns 'off'. A continuous signal, occurs when you have a lever, and then turn it on. The charge continues to be delivered until the lever is turned to the off position. It sounds like you want a pulse, but coming from a lever.

Assuming that this is correct, there are ways to turn a continuous charge into a pulse, and you might want to google the words `minecraft turn signal into pulse`

There is a nice video by Avomance that can show you this. (

)

Comment: This is definitely more of what I was I was looking for especially with a new project I started.  Now to put this to into practice but with a system so open I'm wondering what I could use to hide it? Carpet maybe?

Comment: There is a neat trick where you can put an item frame over redstone, and in that item frame you can put map art, and it totally covers the redstone lines and doesn't interrupt the signal.  Not sure, but I don't think you can put carpets over redstone lines

Answer (score 0):

Make a hopper clock by connecting 2 hoppers and putting an item inside them, then put redstone above the hoppers and connect it to a lever. It will save you space, and is easy to do. Change timing with repeaters.

Comment: I saw that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sDv37gkIlw&list=WL&index=92&t=239s) but when I tried it, it didn't work. It's possible I did something wrong but I was also trying  to explore other techniques if they were available (my minecraft inventory management skills are abysmal).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something I created for my train station a long time ago. I will give you a rough idea on how to achieve your what you want: *How do I make it so that the switch will turn the rail way and then switch it back after I have moved past it?*

Firstly, to answer your question: *...will I have to do the same for the those on each side of the rail switch as well?*

Yes, mostly likely. This is what you maybe after.

[image]

[image]

To summarise the pictures, when the minecarts go over the detectors rails, they allow for the connect rail to be flipped for just enough time to allow the player/entity to return back from the original starting point. Note that the minecarts must be travelling at a decent speed because the change over lasts for seconds only.

The lever in the second picture, if flipped on, will stop the track from changing directions even if the minecart passes over the initial detector rail. This means if you want to travel straight, you need to flip the lever. I have not built a return system if a player were to opt to travel straight. Upon return, they will just turn due to the situation of the connecting rail. You could use this an exercise and build one for the other side yourself.